# Error! Command "npm run build" exited with 1, while deploying a website using vercel command

Tags: javascript, npm, deployment, build, vercel

I am trying to deploy a website on vercel from my command line of VSCode by using the command:

```
vercel
```

When I execute this command, I get this output:
[image: error output]

If I run:

```
vercel logs demo-minting-frontend-rga7f9q73-hemang-h.vercel.app
```

I get the output as follow:

```
PS C:\CS\Three.js\Marketplace-three\Self-coded-creation> vercel logs demo-minting-frontend-rga7f9q73-hemang-h.vercel.app
Vercel CLI 24.0.0
> Fetched deployment "demo-minting-frontend-rga7f9q73-hemang-h.vercel.app" in hemang-h [1s]
2022-03-07T15:36:56.106Z  
2022-03-07T15:36:56.112Z  Retrieving list of deployment files...
2022-03-07T15:36:57.506Z  Downloading 49 deployment files...
2022-03-07T15:36:58.268Z  Analyzing source code...
2022-03-07T15:36:58.657Z  Installing build runtime...
2022-03-07T15:37:01.398Z  Build runtime installed: 2.741s
2022-03-07T15:37:02.062Z  Looking up build cache...
2022-03-07T15:37:05.865Z  Build cache downloaded [87.05 MB]: 3377.740ms
2022-03-07T15:37:06.003Z  Detected package.json
2022-03-07T15:37:06.004Z  Installing dependencies...
2022-03-07T15:37:06.011Z  Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
2022-03-07T15:37:07.781Z  npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
2022-03-07T15:37:08.047Z  
2022-03-07T15:37:08.048Z  added 1 package, and changed 1 package in 2s
2022-03-07T15:37:08.048Z
2022-03-07T15:37:08.048Z  116 packages are looking for funding
2022-03-07T15:37:08.048Z    run `npm fund` for details
2022-03-07T15:37:08.257Z  Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
2022-03-07T15:37:08.257Z  Running "npm run build"
2022-03-07T15:37:08.537Z
2022-03-07T15:37:08.537Z  > demo-minting-page@1.0.0 build
2022-03-07T15:37:08.537Z  > next build
2022-03-07T15:37:08.537Z
2022-03-07T15:37:09.158Z  warn  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-minify-enabled
2022-03-07T15:37:09.177Z  Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2022-03-07T15:37:09.177Z  This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
2022-03-07T15:37:09.177Z  You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following 
URL:
2022-03-07T15:37:09.177Z  https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2022-03-07T15:37:09.177Z
2022-03-07T15:37:09.218Z  info  - Checking validity of types...
2022-03-07T15:37:11.594Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.594Z  Failed to compile.
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  ./pages/404.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  18:9  Warning: passHref is missing. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  ./pages/Landing.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  6:10  Error: 'Text' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  6:16  Error: 'Flex' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.595Z  7:10  Error: 'useState' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  13:5  Error: 'success' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  15:5  Error: 'owned' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  16:5  Error: 'owner' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  26:5  Error: 'reset' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  ./pages/index.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  92:11  Warning: passHref is missing. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  182:11  Warning: passHref is missing. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.596Z  ./pages/mint.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.597Z  1:30  Error: 'SimpleGrid' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.597Z  1:42  Error: 'Divider' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.597Z  3:8  Error: 'Section' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.597Z  4:10  Error: 'WorkGridItem' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  11:28  Error: React Hook "useWeb3Modal" is called in function "mint" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React 
Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks       
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  ./components/grid-item.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  26:5  Warning: passHref is missing. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref  @next/next/link-passhref
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  ./components/mint.js
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  3:30  Error: 'VStack' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  3:52  Error: 'Link' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.598Z  3:58  Error: 'Text' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.599Z  3:64  Error: 'Spacer' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.599Z  5:33  Error: 'IoMdOpen' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.599Z  8:41  Error: 'loading' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u.  no-unused-vars
2022-03-07T15:37:11.599Z  
2022-03-07T15:37:11.599Z  info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
2022-03-07T15:37:11.616Z  Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
2022-03-07T15:37:12.463Z
```

Now, just to say that I tried solving the warnings, I ran:

```
npm install uuid
```

to install the latest uuid version, so that I can bypass the first warning. But It didn't helped either. I again executed `vercel` command, and there were similar logs.

I tried to override the build settings to `CI=False` on vercel, under the project settings, but still didn't got any successful response.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "demo-minting-page",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TokenMinds Demo ",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0",
    "prettier": "prettier -write .",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Hemang Joshi",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.7",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "merkletreejs": "^0.2.30",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "three": "^0.138.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web3": "^1.7.1",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.5",
    "zustand": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json looks like this:

```
{
    "root": true,
    "extends": "next",
    "rules": {
       "plugin":[
            
                "react/recommended"
            
       ],
              "no-unused-vars": [
        "error",
        {
          "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
          "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
        }
      ],
      "react/display-name": 0
    }
}
```

Link to my full github repository where I am holding this code is:
[Github repo](https://github.com/hemang-h/Minting-website-threejs)

Kindly please help me out, what should I do.

P.S:- Everything is working very smoothly on my localhost:3000, and there are not bugs on it. I have ran the `npm run dev` several times on my terminal now, but there are no complaints on the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this problem.

1. It seems that you are importing modules to some js files but not using them so avoid using unnecessary imports and only import a module when you are using it on the page. If you are not using it then avoid importing that module to the js file.

2. Install the following module `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react.` (for developers using NPM) or `yarn add --dev eslint-plugin-react.` (for developers using Yarn)

   Then, in your `.eslintrc.json`, under extends, include the following plugin:

   ```json
   'extends': [
       'plugin:react/recommended'
   ]
   ```

Hopefully, your error will resolve if you use any of this up suggestions

Comment: I have added the edited `.eslintrc.json`  in my question. Is this the way you are asking to write the plugin?

Comment: I see you added under rules then plugin but you have to do it tlike this way

Comment: Remove the plugin from rules and repleace your extends wit this

Comment: `"extends": ["next","plugin:react/recommended"]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is imported variables are never used. Please remove those unused variables, and run `npm run build` in your local machine to see if any error are left out. After that you can redeploy to vercel.

Comment: It shows an error: `error - ESLint: .eslintrc.json:         Configuration for rule "plugin" is invalid:     Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"react/recommended"').`

Comment: I have added `.elsintrc.json` source code in my question, please look there